# how can i control listview located in form1 from form2 to refresh it

Tags: c#, vb.net, forms

I want to refresh a listview1 located in `form1`. I created code that fires a public void to refresh it or make it `listview1.visible = false;` nothing works except `messagebox.show("test");`

How do I make it work?

```
public void RefeshListView()
   {

       this.listView1.BeginUpdate();

       MessageBox.Show("s");//this shows! only:\ !?!?!?
       listView1.Visible = false;
       listView1.Height = 222;
       listView1.EndUpdate();
       listView2.Clear();

   }
```

Comment: What else are you showing???

Comment: Which form is above code located in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little unclear about what you are trying to do, but from your title it sounds like you want to influence the `ListView` on 
Form1 from Form2. I am assuming that Form2 is created from Form1. In your case you have two ways I can think of to do this, the first would be to create a Custom Constructor and pass the Form Instance to it or assign ownership when you show the form. The second would be to create a Custom Event on Form2 and subscribe to that in Form1.

The First Method:

in Form1 when you show Form2 use  `frm2.Show(this);`
in Form2 when you want to call the refresh method  use `((Form1)Parent).RefreshListView();`

or create a Custom Constructor for Form2

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 frm2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm2 = new Form2(this);
        frm2.Show();
    }

    void frm2_RefreshList(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshListView();
    }

    public void RefreshListView()
    {

        this.listView1.BeginUpdate();

        MessageBox.Show("s");//this shows! only:\ !?!?!?
        listView1.Visible = false;
        listView1.Height = 222;
        listView1.EndUpdate();
        listView1.Clear();

    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 frm1;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Form2( Form frm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm1 = (Form1)frm;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm1.RefreshListView();
    }
}
```

The Second Method:

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 frm2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.RefreshList += new EventHandler(frm2_RefreshList);
        frm2.Show();
    }

    void frm2_RefreshList(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshListView();
    }

    public void RefreshListView()
    {

        this.listView1.BeginUpdate();

        MessageBox.Show("s");//this shows! only:\ !?!?!?
        listView1.Visible = false;
        listView1.Height = 222;
        listView1.EndUpdate();
        listView1.Clear();

    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler RefreshList;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshList(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe need refresh.

```
public void RefeshListView()
{

   this.listView1.BeginUpdate();

   MessageBox.Show("s");//this shows! only:\ !?!?!?
   listView1.Visible = false;
   listView1.Height = 222;
   listView1.EndUpdate();
   listView2.Clear();
   listView2.refresh();
}
```